# View BizTalk orchestration code behind in VS2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

My BizTalk (2006) orchestrations open by default in design view. I need to see the file behind (which appears like XML). I don't know how to switch.

With winforms and the like, F7 is the 'go to code' shortcut but I can't find any equivalent for this.

The only thing which sometimes work is to search for a string which appears in the orchestration and within the  code of BizTalk. I have done a search for my string within Search Files (under find) and the Find Results box shows me the string lives in MyFile.odx (and it displays the ). However, I can't get the actual code on screen as it only shows the design view.

So, just to make sure this is really clear, I want to switch between the 2 screen shots:

From the Design View:

[image]

to the 'code behind' view:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around, I can open it from Windows Explorer in notepad. Not ideal, but at least I'm not stuck any more.

Comment: I won't if OK - a work around is not an answer. I have been able to display the XML in visual studio by luck and I'm convinced there must be a way more elegant than just performing a search and hoping the correct display is shown! Or, it is a faulty with my installation of VS and your post is the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Right click -> Open with.. -> XML Editor

[image]

Comment: I had tried this and the error message VS shows is "The file cannot be opened with the selected editor. Please choose another editor."